# C# Web Service client cast error

Tags: c#, java, web-services, web

I am  trying to consume a  Java web service but  get an exception System.InvalidCastException: Cannot assign object of type ValueArrayType to an object of type ValueArrayType[]

I am consuming a third party service so cannot change  the service and have been informed that they can consume the service ok with php and java.

Value Array type is  complex type

```
 <xsd:complexType name="ValueArrayType">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="ValueName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="ValueType" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="ValueValue" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

It is an element in the response DetailsType that can have several occurrences as it  has max = unbound and is wrapped by a sequence attribute.

```
<xsd:complexType name="DetailsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="Id" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="MobileName" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="ValueArray" type="tns:ValueArrayType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

I have tried wsdll.exe and svrcutil.exe to try and  generate client code.
the ValueArrayType is defined in the generated code as  an array.

```
public ValueArrayType[] ValueArray
{
    get
    {
        return this.valueArrayField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.valueArrayField = value;
    }
}
```

an example of  the data coming back is.

```
....
<Details xsi:type="tns:DetailsType">
    <Id xsi:type="xsd:int">9999</Id>
    <ValueArray xsi:type="tns:ValueArrayType">
      <ValueName xsi:type="xsd:string">Count</ValueName>
      <ValueType xsi:type="xsd:string">numeric</ValueType>
      <ValueValue xsi:type="xsd:string">11</ValueValue>
    </ValueArray>
    <ValueArray xsi:type="tns:ValueArrayType">
      <ValueName xsi:type="xsd:string">Start</ValueName>
      <ValueType xsi:type="xsd:string">numeric</ValueType>
      <ValueValue xsi:type="xsd:string">31</ValueValue>
    </ValueArray>
    <ValueArray xsi:type="tns:ValueArrayType">
      <ValueName xsi:type="xsd:string">A1</ValueName>
      <ValueType xsi:type="xsd:string">numeric</ValueType>
      <ValueValue xsi:type="xsd:string">23</ValueValue>
    </ValueArray>
    <ValueArray xsi:type="tns:ValueArrayType">
      <ValueName xsi:type="xsd:string">A2</ValueName>
      <ValueType xsi:type="xsd:string">numeric</ValueType>
      <ValueValue xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ValueValue>
    </ValueArray>
    <ValueArray xsi:type="tns:ValueArrayType">
      <ValueName xsi:type="xsd:string">X1</ValueName>
      <ValueType xsi:type="xsd:string">numeric</ValueType>
      <ValueValue xsi:type="xsd:string">0</ValueValue>
    </ValueArray>
    .....
```

If I change  the  client code to  public ValueArrayType ValueArray
instead of an array then the  client works but only gets the first ValueArray returned.

Have tried suggestions from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2007/02/01/why-your-netcf-apps-fail-to-call-some-web-services.aspx.

**Update** 
I have generated  a WCF Service with  the proxyclass generated from scvutil.
When  I consume  and check  the xml with  WCFTestCLient.exe.

An Array type is sent back as

```
<ValueArray>
      <ValueArrayType>
        <ValueName>a</ValueName>
        <ValueType>string</ValueType>
        <ValueValue>1</ValueValue>
      </ValueArrayType>
      <ValueArrayType>
        <ValueName>a</ValueName>
        <ValueType>string</ValueType>
        <ValueValue>2</ValueValue>
      </ValueArrayType>
 </ValueArray>
```

I assume either the data being sent does not match the WSDL or there is a bug in the C# scvutil, or System.ServiceModel.

Comment: Would a manual solution be enough? It should not be too hard to write a XSL transform for the data coming from the server and then serialise the resulting XML into the wanted object... I know it is a lot of boring boiler plate code to write but once done it may prove a more robust solution than to rely on a tool...

Comment: yeah, that is a solution, but I as we consume many  java webservices not something i want to do every time.   It seems there is communication layer issue with the way Java does things and the way  C# does things

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your element type inside the generated code

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "ValueArray", Type = typeof(ValueArrayType), Namespace = "YourSchemaNamespace")]
        public ValueArrayType[] ValueArray
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueArrayField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueArrayField = value;
            }
        }
```

More information is available at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)

Comment: sorry same invalid cast excpetion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by incorrect xsi:type values that mislead WCF deserialization ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467086/17122)).

The workaround is to use `OperationFormatUse.Literal` instead of `OperationFormatUse.Encoded` on all operations.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try something like this ?

JavaServecie js= new JavaService();

js.ValueArrayType arr= js.GetValues(.....

if the class is public.

Comment: Sorry  not following,  are you suggesting this at the get/set property for the   generated  ServiceContract code? I am assuming it is failing when trying to deserialize the xml to the defined types, so an apporpriate ServiceContract attribute on this type and/or getter/setetter code might be the solution.

Comment: If I add a .net webservice and the service has a public reference to a customclass like (employer,product etc) then you can use that class in the client as service.Employer emp = new service.employer();

Comment: Sorry I still don't follow as I need to send a request  to the WebMethod of the webservice and then consumer the response? How does creating a class of this type help?

Comment: I might have understood you wrong, but I thought the return from your webmethod call would be of the class, that I just talked about.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are suggesting

Comment: @rqmedes Don't worry. Nobody understands.